# Ctrl+Click to select Gallery items in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an image gallery in Bootstrap, where I click on the items to select it (just highlight) and multiple select with CTRL key. I can do this with jQuery, just wondering if its already available in bootstrap

Comment: I think, no one done yet. However, can you please share your desired markup? bootply.com or jsfiddle.net is enough. We can try using http://jqueryui.com/selectable/ with your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqueryui.com/selectable does all the above mentioned features including CTRL+Click and drag-to-select features.